# jpanel.add(component) doesnt work when inside an actionListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I am currently still learning this spell called swing so i wrote this code

```
    lblWarning = new JLabel("<html>Incorrect Username or Password<br/>   please try again!</html>");
        lblWarning.setBounds(10,121,220,48);
        lblWarning.setForeground(new Color(150, 0, 0));
        lblWarning.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblWarning.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));



        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Confirm");
        btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font("Microsoft JhengHei", Font.BOLD, 14));
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                if(txtUsername.getText()!="user" && txtPassword.getText()!="pass") {
                    contentPane.add(lblWarning);
                }else {

                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(10, 180, 94, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);
```

txtusername and txtpassword are text fields btw. but the problem is contentPane (jpanel) doesnt add the label "lblWarning" when the conditions are true but works and shows fine when its outside the actionListener, whats the problem ?

Comment: The button btnNewButton_1 is not added to any any other component. Hw are you going to click it?

Comment: if you mean this
  contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);
then its there i just forgot to paste it here

Comment: Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Post a proper [mre] when asking a question so we can better understand the context of your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. How do you know your "if condition" is ever true? Did you do basic debugging by adding a `System.out.println(...)` statement to verify you are executing the code inside the statement?
2. Don't use "==" or "!=" to compare a String. Instead use the `String.equals(...)` method.
3. After you add a component to a visible frame you need to also invoke `panel.revalidate()`, to invoke the layout manager so the component is given  a size/location.

Comment: for your first question i did this 
`
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    contentPane.add(lblWarning);
               
            }
        });
`
it still didn't work

3- if you mean
`
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    
                   contentPane.add(lblWarning);
        
                   contentPane.revalidate();
               
            }
        });
`
it didnt work either

Comment: Don't post code in comments. The code is unreadable. Update your code showing how you implemented all 3 suggestions. And update the code to be an [mre]. That is post your demo that contains the frame, your two text fields and the button, so we can see exactly what you are doing. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test the code.